# MS SQL: How to select the most recent record from a lookup table for each foreign key pair

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a lookup table which consists of two foreign keys which form a unique pair.  These unique pairs are repeated a number of times within the table each time a transaction is made, with a new date/time being recorded each time.

I need to find a way to return just the "most recent" record for each foreign key pairing, and be able to apply additional filtering to it with a WHERE statement.

Here's an example of the table:

```
PK     PartPK  LocationPK  TransactionDate          Bin
16473  1       1           2018-09-03 15:24:57.100  NULL
16472  1       1           2018-09-03 13:24:27.250  NULL
16471  1       1           2018-09-03 13:07:11.777  NULL
16470  1       1           2018-09-03 11:19:57.557  NULL
16469  1       2           2018-09-03 09:32:27.050  NULL
16468  2       1           2018-09-03 07:28:16.250  NULL
16467  2       1           2018-09-03 00:09:30.383  NULL
16466  2       1           2018-08-31 14:21:24.803  NULL
16465  2       1           2018-08-31 13:29:52.253  NULL
16463  3       1           2018-08-31 13:13:47.977  NULL
```

The correct query should be able to give the following result:

```
PK     PartPK  LocationPK  TransactionDate          Bin
16473  1       1           2018-09-03 15:24:57.100  NULL
16469  1       2           2018-09-03 09:32:27.050  NULL
16468  2       1           2018-09-03 07:28:16.250  NULL
16463  3       1           2018-08-31 13:13:47.977  NULL
```

For each distinct PartPK and LocationPK pairing, I just want the row with the greatest TransactionDate value.  I would also like to be able to build on this by adding a "WHERE Bin is null" to the query, to further limit the results.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` function :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by PartPK, LocationPK order by PK desc) as seq -- you can also order by TransactionDate
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was ideal!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Q2.* FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t.PartPK, t.LocationPK FROM Yourtab t) Q1
                CROSS APPLY 
                    (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Yourtab t2 
                            WHERE t2.PartPK = Q1.PartPK AND t2.LocationPK = Q1.LocationPK 
                                ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC) Q2
```

Answer (score 1):

First we should simply fetch the most recent `PK` of each `PartPK and LocationPK` then we can use it as subquery to return complete record of that `PK` as given below:

```
CREATE TABLE #test(PK INT, PartPK INT, LocationPK INT, TransactionDate DATETIME, Bin INT)
INSERT INTO #test VALUES
(16473,1,1,'2018-09-03 15:24:57.100',NULL),
(16472,1,1,'2018-09-03 13:24:27.250',NULL),
(16471,1,1,'2018-09-03 13:07:11.777',NULL),
(16470,1,1,'2018-09-03 11:19:57.557',NULL),
(16469,1,2,'2018-09-03 09:32:27.050',NULL),
(16468,2,1,'2018-09-03 07:28:16.250',NULL),
(16467,2,1,'2018-09-03 00:09:30.383',NULL),
(16466,2,1,'2018-08-31 14:21:24.803',NULL),
(16465,2,1,'2018-08-31 13:29:52.253',NULL),
(16463,3,1,'2018-08-31 13:13:47.977',NULL)

SELECT t.* 
FROM #test t
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT MAX(PK) AS PK --We can use `TransactionDate` as well
            FROM #test
            GROUP BY PartPK, LocationPK) t1 ON t.PK = t1.PK
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
PK      PartPK  LocationPK  TransactionDate         Bin
16473   1       1           2018-09-03 15:24:57.100 NULL
16469   1       2           2018-09-03 09:32:27.050 NULL
16468   2       1           2018-09-03 07:28:16.250 NULL
16463   3       1           2018-08-31 13:13:47.977 NULL
```